# Integrating a RTOS like Erika Enterprise on a hypervisor that can run AUTOSAR application?

Tags: can-bus, rtos, xen, autosar, automotive

I'm new to automotive applications and trying to understand the stack for automotive systems. My goal is to implement a system where I can test AUTOSAR applications.

Currently, I'm looking to implement this using the following configuration below:

- x86_64, Common Desktop PC (Hardware)
- Xen (Hypervisor)
- Erika Enterprise (RTOS, run as guest VM)
- RT-Druid (for Erika/AUTOSAR application development, on a different development machine)

There is already
[reference material](http://www.erika-enterprise.com/wiki/index.php?title=ERIKA3_on_the_Xen_hypervisor)
on how to setup Xen and Erika on x86 hardware.

## Questions:

1. How do I run an Erika/AUTOSAR application on this setup. Lets say a simple "Hello World" example. Do I simply copy and paste it on my VM and run?
2. Is there already an implementation of CAN bus on Erika Enterprise? How do I implement this feature on my setup?

Comment: I have the fealing that not all of the tags are relevant to the core of your question.  @Thor - are you sure all are relevant? E.g., do you have problems setting up **the virtualization with XEN**, **the CAN bus** or the **RTOS support** within that virtualisation? Having specified [autosar], do you really need the [automotive] tag?

Comment: Yes I think all tags are relevant, basically I need help in a setup where a virtualized setup of an RTOS (Erika) with support implementation of CAN bus in Xen that can run AUTOSAR applications. This is Automotive Application.

Comment: For a AUTOSAR Classic, you should keep in mind, that the OS, RTE and BSW is part of the whole application.That means, your "Hello World" conatins your SWCs plus BSW, OS (including Tasks/ISRs) and RTE (incl the connections to below RTE). You should also make sure, to stay the complete AUTOSAR abstracted way of layers in order to access HW, because the drivers can then be abstracted e,g, with Windows driver implementations. I don't know, if Erika OS provides AUTOSAR BSW components like CommStack (driver, CanIf, PduR, (Ld)Com and SystemServices like ComM and BswM.